# How to style a scrollbar for a horizontal scroll list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

Attempting to style a scrollbar for a horizontal scroll list to create the style found here: http://manos.malihu.gr/code-example/horizontal-custom-scrollbar-tutorial/
(Also would like to change the color of the scroller)

The jQuery mCustomScrollBar function dosen't seem to work.
Here is a link to my code: https://codepen.io/KevinM818/pen/WEjBVW

```
<section class="productSlider">
        <div class="prodList">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
                <li class="prodItem"><a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

```
.productSlider {
    padding: 100px 0;
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .prodList {
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 82%;
        .prodItem {
            padding: 0 50px;
        }
        .list-inline {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    }
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on("load",function(){
    $(".prodList").mCustomScrollbar({
      axis:"x",
      theme:"dark-3"
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Check whether you have added the mCustomscrollbar plugin in your html 
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have added the mcustomscrollbar in your

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
<script src="//malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
```

Change your jQuery as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prodList").mCustomScrollbar({
      axis:"x",
      theme:"dark-3"
    });
});
```

And in CSS change .prodList overflow-x value to auto